# removing tag from textarea with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

How to remove the a tag but the content in it to remain?

Something like this:

```
<textarea  id="temp">
    ff<a href="sds.jpg" rel="tt[images]" title="">  cissttppp  </a>
</textarea>
```

To become:

```
<textarea  id="temp">ff  cissttppp  </textarea>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$('#temp').val(function(i,val) {
    return $('<div>').html(val).text();
});
```

**Live Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/Pzny9/

Answer (score 2):

how about a nice little injection using your code?

http://jsfiddle.net/4dTEQ/

```
<textarea  id="temp"><img onerror="alert((function(a){ return 'injection!'; })())" src=" sffsdfds" />ff<a href="sds.jpg" rel="tt[images]" title="">  cissttppp  </a></textarea>
```

Comment: This would be more appropriated as a comment on the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Added an id for a

```
<textarea  id="temp">ff<a href="sds.jpg" rel="tt[images]" title="" id="someA">  cissttppp  </a></textarea>  


var temporary= $("#someA").text();  
$("#someA").remove();  
$("#temp").text($("#temp").text()+temporary);
```