# Trying to remove all html from a element with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a DIV element that's filled with a bunch of HTML entities that I want to remove:

```
<div class="text">
<p>&lt;p&gt;&#8203;&lt;span style="line-height:25px;"&gt;&#8203;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;span style="line-height:25px;"&gt;&#8203;Hej hop!&lt;/span&gt;&nbsp;&lt;span style="line-height:25px;"&gt;&#8203;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;span</p>
</div>
```

I'm using jQuery and created this code but it isn't working:

```
$('.text').each(function () {
    $(this).replace(/<\/?[a-z][a-z0-9]*[^<>]*>/ig, "");
});
```

I'm trying to replace the text with the phrase "Hej Hop!".

The regex is not wrong..

Here is how I did it with some other pages:

```
    text = text.replace(/<\/?[a-z][a-z0-9]*[^<>]*>/ig, "");
```

But this was in a javascript function with parameters that returned the text.. But on this specific page I need to use jquery and iterate and check...

Question Solved:

```
$('text').each(function () {
    $(this).html(function (i, v) {
        return $('<div>').html(v).text();
    });
});
```

Comment: `$(this).html($(this).text())`?

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking for here.

Comment: when you say `html code`, do you mean `HTML Entities`?

Comment: What's "generating" the HTML?  Why not just make it stop?

Comment: to be clear. Do u want function to strip or remove any html code and return only the normal text??

Comment: @Pointy Beacuse its Sharepoint :>

Comment: @ebramtharwat Yeah I want to strip any html code inside the text class and only return the normal text

Comment: I believe your regular expression is incorrect.  I can't tell you what the right one would be, but you can use a testing website like http://regexpal.com/ to check.

Comment: This html breaks the page when it is rendered. So it must be amended before placing it on the page.

Comment: check these questions they also ask for the same functionality: [removing tag from textarea with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6013063/removing-tag-from-textarea-with-jquery) OR check this : [Strip html tags before callback](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12277408/strip-html-tags-before-callback)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can strip them like this using [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html-functionindex--oldhtml)

```
$('div.text').html(function(i,v){
    return $('<div>').html(v).text();
    // create new div - append HTML and get the text from the div
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UA9P9/

It still leaves some characters in there so you will probably need to regex them out with your regex

```
$('div.text').html(function(i,v){
     return $.trim($('<div>').html(v).text().replace(/<\/?[a-z][a-z0-9]*[^<>]*>/ig, ""));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VfxaT/

Answer (score 7):

You just need:

```
$('.text').empty();
```

*edit* — if you want to remove the **markup** from the contents of the element, the simplest thing to do would be what Marc B suggested in a comment:

```
$('.text').each(function() {
  $(this).text($(this).text());
});
```

Comment: I think he wanted to keep the text though? Just not the html.

Comment: I agree, it is very vague.

Comment: i think u get the question wrong..i don't understand what the votes up for

Comment: @ebramtharwat answer amended :-) The question was a little vague originally.

Comment: This one removes everything.. I just want to remove the html codes inside the text class.

Answer (score 0):

These are Ascii code so the Regex for that is: `/xxx[\x00-\x7F]+xxx/`